# Why Class.getClass() can be different from Class.cast() return type?

Tags: java, casting

I hope you can assist me on this matter.

I've been looking for answers to this question but all I could find was related to generic type usage or general instructions about reflection.

Say we have a parent class and a child class which extends that parent. So, see below:

```
Parent v = new Child();
```

If I make `v.getClass()` it returns `Child`. However, if I make `v.getClass().cast()` it returns an object from type `Parent`.

Anyone knows why it happens? I also took a look at the Java API documentation and couldn't find a reason...

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: I think you should review the `polymorphism` in Java.

Comment: What object are you passing to your cast()?

Comment: Doesn't `cast` require an argument?

Comment: As argument I would use an instance of `Child` to cast it as `Child` instead of `Parent`. The main problem here is that I have some methods in different children classes that are exclusive (eg. `Child1` has `methodA()` and `Child2` has `methodB()`, both extending `Parent`) and I need to call them. The compiler won't allow me as it's typed as `Parent`.

Comment: Because that's exactly what Class.cast() is for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's an important distinction between what the runtime type of an object and the compile-time type of a variable or expression is. The compile-time type of an expression can *only* be determined from the compile-time types of its components. The runtime types of objects that are the values of these expressions may be determined from the runtime types of the parameters of the expression, as long as they are compatible with the compile-time types.

To illustrate this, in your specific code sample:

- The variable `v` has the **compile-time** type `Parent`, but the **runtime** type of the value assigned to it will be `Child`.
- The expression `v.getClass()` will have the **compile-time** type `Class<? extends Parent>` (a class object representing either the  `Parent` type or one of its subclasses.). Its value at **runtime** will be `Child.class` which is of type `Class<Child>`.
- The expression `v.getClass().cast(obj)` will have the **compile-time** type `Parent`. It's **runtime** type will be *the runtime type of `obj`*, because its runtime value will, in fact, be `obj` itself. (That is, if obj is of a type that's assignable to a variable of type `Child`, otherwise `cast()` will throw a `ClassCastException`)

Comment: +1, this was better than the answer I deleted before yours :) I gave up trying to make sense.

Comment: At runtime, v.getClass() will be Class<Child> . and calling cast(obj) will try and cast the object to Child -- not Parent.

Comment: @Kal Thanks, seems I got a little tangled up towards the end.

Comment: Your answer is right on. I "think" the OP is trying to figure out why `Child c1 = v.getClass().cast(obj);` won't compile and your second bullet explains it

Comment: @Inerdia, great answer. My final quest is: what if `Child1` has an exclusive method `methodA()` and `Child2` has an exclusive method `methodB()`? How can I call them in the code if I need to cast the object in runtime?

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes: The Proper (tm) solution is using the Visitor pattern. The quick and dirty solution is `if (child instanceof Child1) { ((Child1) child).methodA(); } else if (child instanceof Child2) {…}`

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes Conceptually, `methodA()` and `methodB()` are completely unrelated to the `Parent` type. That means the type system can't provide a way to let you call either of them using the base type.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been looking for answers to this question but all I could find was related to generic type usage or general instructions about reflection.

You receive a `Class<Parent>` as that is the compile time type.

```
//compiletime v is of type Parent
Parent v = new Child(); 
//The class of a Parent object is either the Parent class or a child Class
Class<? extends Parent> cls = v.getClass();
//The return type of cast is the at compile time known upper bound, here it is 
//Parent, which is true since every Child object is also a Parent object.  
cls.cast(...);
//Note that this will throw a runtime exception, since it will perform a 
//cast to child at runtime. The cast uses the Child class at runtime and
//fails for other instances of Parent.
cls.cast(new Parent());
```

Here a simplified example for what you can use it.

```
class Test<T>{
  public Test(Class<T> cls){clazz = cls;}
  ArrayList<T> list = ...;
  Class<T> clazz;
  void add(Object o){
     list.add((T)o);//Cast does nothing at runtime
     list.add(clazz.cast(o)); //casts o to T
  }
}
```

A normal cast in the form (T)o does not work in java as the generic type T is not known at runtime. The jvm only sees the upper bound (Object) cast which never fails. Using the cast method with a reference to the actual class instead is a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of design of getClass() method and generics.

For compatibility reasons, getClass() method have not made generic, so it returns instance of type

```
Class<?>
```

not

```
Class<Child>
```

as you could expect.

```
Class<?>
```

means generic type with type parameter of Object.

So, the return type of

```
Class<?>.cast()
```

method is Object. I.e. generic nature of this method does not work.

You can write

```
v3 = ( (Class<Child>) v.getClass() ).cast(v2);
```

but this is senseless since you can just write

```
v3 = ( Child ) v.getClass().cast(v2);
```

Also, you should remember, that generics work only at compile time. I.e. genercis are only for type checking at your IDE. At runtime all generics are

```
<?>
```

So, actually, cast() method does nothing at runtime. This is only a stub to use when you have instances of type

```
Class<something>
```

Comment: From the documentation of [`Object.getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()):

“The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.” `.getClass()` is generic.