# Polymorphism confusion: How to access the correct class from `Constructor.getInstance()`?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, casting, variadic-functions

I have a base class called `BaseMatrix`, and several children thereof. I have pre-created instances of these children to do some unit tests on and put them in a list `toUnitTest`.

However, I'd also like to test all my constructors, so I thought to take advantage of my pre-created instances using `m.getClass()` to make a new object of the same type but with a different constructor. For example, one such constructor takes a `double[][]`. I found out that `Constructor.newInstance()` returns `Object`, so I tried to cast it:

```
    // This is in the unit test class.
    
    private static double[][] testArr = new double[][]{{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
    private static ArrayList<BaseMatrix> toUnitTest = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void startUp() {
        toUnitTest.add(new ND4JDenseMatrix(testRows, testCols));
        toSpeedTest.add(new JamaDenseMatrix(testRows, testCols));
        toSpeedTest.add(new EjmlDenseMatrix(testRows, testCols));
        toSpeedTest.add(new ColtDenseMatrix(testRows, testCols));
    }

    @Test
    void createFromArray(){
        for (BaseMatrix m : toUnitTest) {
            try {
                Constructor c = m.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(double[][].class);
                BaseMatrix M = m.getClass().cast(c.newInstance(testArr));
                // ... some assertions to check the data ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This results in an illegal argument exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919315/3696204), I think I am casting my child back to the parent class, which doesn't have this constructor that just takes a `double[][]`. All of the child classes have the constructor that takes this argument, so I think I just need to figure out how to correctly cast. How might I do this?

Comment: One thing isn't clear to me.. why are you trying to cast? Why don't you simply add the new instance to the list?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I already have a list of objects for other test purposes (namely mathy stuff). Now, I need to test that all the constructors are working. So, since I have a set of instances, I can use them to get the other unique constructors and test them in a for loop. I don't need those instances after the constructor is proved to be working, so I don't want to add those objects to my test array.

Comment: Why don't you store the classes instead of instances? Why create an instance just to do getClass()?

Comment: I wouldn't design my test like that honestly, but rather have a dedicated test class with a test for each constructor. I see that you're trying to avoid wasting code for that but what you try to do is dangerous. It is technically feasible, but it may hide stuff (for example what if someone extends your base class and creates some complex logic over construction? How would you know what to test and if the creation of the instance actually worked functionally?)

Comment: Can you post the code for BaseMatrix? At least the constructors. I agree with @MatteoNNZ, the tests should test each implementation explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static double[][] testArr = new double[][]{{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
// ,,,
            Constructor c = m.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(double[][].class);
            BaseMatrix M = m.getClass().cast(c.newInstance(testArr));
```

`Constructor.newInstance` takes `Object[]` as its parameter, which uses varargs. The code passes a `double[][]` which is an instance of `Object[]` because of the bizarre way reference arrays work in Java.

Before J2SE 5.0, methods such as `newInstance` could not be varargified, so for backward compatibility any single argument that is assignable to an appropriate array has the `...` interpreted as `[]`.

An easy fix would be to explicitly create the array as if there the method didn't use varargs.

```
c.newInstance(new Object[] { testArr })
```

The other notable issue is that `c` is declared as the raw type `Constructor`. This should give a warning (heed warnings!). So

```
            Constructor<? extends BaseMatrix> c = // ...
```

Comment: This indeed worked. One of the comments suggests that perhaps the way I am doing things isn't best practice. Would you agree?

Comment: @rocksNwaves I would avoid reflection altogether. Factories would be better.

Comment: Shorter: `c.newInstance((Object)testArr)`